# Restrict parts of geth API RPC methods

Tags: ethereum, geth

I'm running an ethereum node with the geth client. I would like to be able to use the `admin.peers` command through RPC without allowing the use of the other commands in the admin namespace.

Is there a way to go about this? If not, how can I get this information from my node remotely?

Answer (score 2):

Not with native geth. One way you could do it is to set up a nginx reverse proxy server that sees what function is being called, and then filter that way.